# Loading json file into iOS Cordova is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, json, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm working with Cordova framework to generate an app on iOS device; I have a JSON file and I am trying to load it by using XMLHttpRequest().

```
let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        let nodes = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        groomNodes('', nodes);
        nodeDescriptionLoaded = true;
        for (let i in todo_assocs) { 
            tuple = todo_assocs[i];
            subscribe(tuple.path, tuple.func, tuple.sessionid);
        }
        todo_assocs = [];
        if (typeof (cb) == 'function')
            cb();
        else
            UTILS.report('please provide a callback to 
                          nodepool.run(callback) - it will be 
                          called as soon asthings are set');
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "resources/json/concom.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But sadly its not reaching the function onreadystatechange() and reporting no errors!!!

I tried the same method open web and Android device and its working perfectly.

Any ideas what should I do to make it work on iOS? 
Is there any other way beside XMLHttpRequest to load the JSON file?

Comment: Are you sure its not reaching `onreadystatechange` ? Add log BEFORE `if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ....)`. Maybe it just not found `concom.json`

Comment: I tried this and there was no return error. 
It is just failing silently..

Comment: Or try to make an else, log `xmlhttp` and ad it to you question

Comment: Where should I make an else? Because I am not even reaching the function onreadystatechange. 
But I found another solution; embedding JSON into JS code to load it, and its working. 
But Im asking for another solution because I don't think embedding into JS is the best solution

Comment: Hmm sorry. It can be due to whitelist plugin ?